# How to plot a time series with multi-index of month and year

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I try to plot a time series where the multi-index is equal to the year and month. This makes python crash when I try to plot with matplotlib. How can I combine these two indexes into one index that is just a date_time variable?

So what I want is to combine the multi-index into one index, changing the two columns into one column (e.g.: 2018  1 -->  2018/01). How can I achieve this?

The picture below shows the dataframe I'm working with.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime([f'{a}-{b}-01' for a, b in df.index])
```

If possible converting to integers `year`s:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime([f'{int(a)}-{b}-01' for a, b in df.index])
```

If possible converting to integers failed, because missing values use:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime([f'{a}-{b}-01' for a, b in df.index], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thx, that works. I see the problem I was facing was that the year is a float and not an integer... pd.to_datetime doesn't see a float variable year as a year somehow.

Comment: @MilesBennetDyson - answer was edited.